# C++ How to inherit from interface with a method of other interface type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have this structure:

```
class IA
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class IB
{
    virtual IA bar() = 0;
};
```

So far I made the inherited versions of these two interfaces but I have difficulties with how to make concrete overriding of the `IA IB::bar()` method?

I mean if I have a class `A` inheriting from `IA` then how to declare the `A bar()` method in a class `B` which inherits of `IB`? Or perhaps I should make a third class for this matter?

Thanks!

Edit: Now I have noticed that the `bar()` definition in `IB` is as follows:

```
virtual IA& bar() = 0;
```

Perhaps this will help?

Comment: `virtual IA bar()` cannot be implemented, because you cannot create an instance of `IA`.  Did you intend to have it return a pointer or reference to `IA` that points to an object of a class derived from `IA`?

Comment: @MilesBudnek unfortunately I cannot touch this structure. I just have to inherit from it.

Comment: @winsett Like Miles said, `IA IB::bar()` cannot be implemented. `IB::bar()` **must** return either an `IA*` pointer or `IA&` reference instead. Even if `IA` weren't abstract, returning an `IA` by value without a pointer/reference would still not work, as `bar()` would [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) any derived object it tried to return.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, you are right - I had a second look on it and its return type is of ```IA&```. I had missed this at my first glance and this somehow confused me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of subtle differences between Java and C++. If you come from a Java background, a value of type `IA` is of type `IA` or any subclass thereof. But in C++, a value of type `IA` is a concrete instance of `IA`, *nothing more and nothing less*. And your `IA` is abstract, hence there are no concrete instances, so as written, your `IB::bar` is unsatisfiable. There's no well-defined function that can ever have that type.

Instead, when you want to do Java-style inheritance-based polymorphism (which is often not the answer in C++, but we'll assume it's the right tool for the job for the moment), you need a layer of indirection. That can be a raw pointer (`IA*`), a reference (`IA&`), or a smart pointer (`unique_ptr<IA>`).

By convention, we return a smart pointer if the data is intended to be *owned* by the caller (i.e. the caller is responsible for freeing it when done), a reference if it's owned by someone else, and a raw pointer if we want our fellow programmers to suffer. I'll assume you intend that the caller own the `IA` value, so we'll use a smart pointer.

Your interfaces can be written

```
#include <memory>

class IA {
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class IB {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<IA> bar() = 0;
};
```

And we can concretely implement them as follows

```
class A : public IA {
  virtual void foo() {}
};

class B : public IB {
  virtual std::unique_ptr<IA> bar() {
    return std::make_unique<A>();
  }
};
```

Comment: Objects in Java are passed around by pointer, not by value. Even if the Java syntax doesn't suggest pointers are being used, they are.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I have noticed I missed that the return type of ```boo()``` is reference of ```IA```. Your answer forced me to take a second look as at first glance I have missed this detail. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
class IA
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class IB
{
public:
    virtual IA& bar() = 0;
};
```

```cpp
class A : public IA
{
public:
    void foo() override;
};

class B : public IB
{
private:
    A m_a;
public:
    IA& bar() override;
};
```

```cpp
void A::foo() {
    ...
}

IA& B::bar() {
    return m_a;
}
```